# php using curl get file content but garbled characters

Tags: php, html, curl

I use the curl to get the file content from amazon s3. but response data has some garbred like this:

```
ÿþ<�html> <�body> <�a href="#url>alsdkfjasdfkj
```

But the text is ok when I write the response data into a file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#url>alsdkfjasdfkj
```

whether I read content from response data nor I write data from the new file, I get the same content and grabled inside above.

How could I resolve it? I want to get the regular text and do something else and next ... etc...

I want to get the regular response data like

```
<html><body>......</body></html>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 60;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: my url is relevant amazon s3, it actually is a file name not a truly url @QuỳnhNguyễn

Comment: We need more clue for help you. That's not enough. Provide code, $url or anything so we can help.